# Conflito de versão do PHP

Tags: php

Eu testei um script para integrar formulários com o Mailchimp:

```
<?php
    // MailChimp API URL
    $memberID   = md5(strtolower($email_popup));
    $dataCenter = substr($apiKey,strpos($apiKey,'-')+1);
    $url        = 'https://' . $dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $listID . '/members/' . $memberID;

    // member information
    $json = json_encode([
        'email_address' => $email_popup,
        'status'        => 'subscribed',
        'merge_fields'  => [
            'FNAME'   => $nome_empresa_popup,
            'CIDADE'  => $cidade_estado_popup,
            'MMERGE4' => $vendedor_popup
        ]
    ]);

    // send a HTTP POST request with curl
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $apiKey);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

No servidor do meu site, funcionou corretamente.

Mas no servidor do cliente, está dando o seguinte erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /home/{dominio}/public_html/{site}/paginas/modal.php on line 511

Que é nessa linha:

```
$json = json_encode([
```

Eu procurei na documentação do PHP algo, mas não encontrei nada relativo à erro de sintaxe.

Comment: Tente trocar a forma como você declara o array, ao invés de colocar assim [] coloque array()

Comment: qual a versão do php do servidor do cliente?

Comment: A do meu site é a 5.6. A do cliente é a 5.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenta fazer assim:

```
$json = json_encode(array(
    'email_address' => $email_popup,
    'status'        => 'subscribed',
    'merge_fields'  => array(
        'FNAME'   => $nome_empresa_popup,
        'CIDADE'  => $cidade_estado_popup,
        'MMERGE4' => $vendedor_popup
    )
));
```

Comment: Eram as chaves mesmo. Aprendendo mais uma. Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Vou prestar mais atenção antes de colocar aqui. Eu venho para cá em último caso mesmo. Mas vou prestar mais atenção.

Answer (score 4):

A função `json_encode` só funciona na versão do php 5.2 ou superior, e esta forma de escrever um array utilizando apenas chaves [] só funciona na versão do php 5.4 ou superior.

Fontes:

- [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php)
- [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Eu acredito que a sua versão não seja inferior a 5.2, o problema deve esta ao declarar o array, você pode resolver o problema colocando o código da seguinte forma:

```
$merge_fields = array(
        'FNAME'   => $nome_empresa_popup,
        'CIDADE'  => $cidade_estado_popup,
        'MMERGE4' => $vendedor_popup
);

$array_json = array(
    'email_address' => $email_popup,
    'status'        => 'subscribed',
    'merge_fields'  => $merge_fields
);

$json = json_encode($array_json);
```